# How to load a trust store file to below code in Spring Java

Tags: java, spring

I'm having a working code to communicate with a server, but now a trust store file is added to server to authenticate. How to add trust `store.jks` file to the code below:

My Java code:

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keyStore.load(new FileInputStream("/users/Documents/workspace/publickey.cert"),
                "password".toCharArray());
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                new SSLContextBuilder()
                        .loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
                        .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, "changeit".toCharArray()).build());
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory).build();
        ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(
                httpClient);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);

    ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange("url",  HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<String>(), String.class);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you imported your `.cert` file correctly to the `store.jks` file, you can do something like this to load up the `store.jks` file (or continue to use the method you are currently using to load up a file).

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream instream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("store.jks");
keyStore.load(instream, "JKSpassword".toCharArray());
instream.close();
```

From there it is the same except when you `loadTrustMaterial` for the `SSLContextBuilder`

```
SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
    new SSLContextBuilder()
        .loadTrustMaterial(keyStore, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy()).build());
```

Hope this helps.